# TwoSum | Expected: [0, 1], instead got: [0, 0] | Ruby indexs' problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def two_sum(nums, tg)
  b = []
  nums.sort.combination(2){|x| b << x}
  c = b.reject{|x| x.sum != tg}[0]
  [nums.index(c[0]), nums.index(c[1])]
end
```

Input

```
two_sum([2, 2, 3], 4)
```

Output

```
Expected: [0, 1], instead got: [0, 0]
```

How can I slove this problem? I've tried something with Hash... I'd appreciate also any suggestion how to make my code cleaner because I'm beginner. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that, given an array of integers `nums` and an integer `tg`, you wish to find a pair of distinct indices `i` and `j` such that `num[i] + num[j] == tg` is `true`. (It's important to start every question with a precise statement of the problem.)

Let's first see why you are getting an incorrect result.

```
nums = [2, 2, 3]
tg = 4
```

```
b = []
x1 = nums.sort
  #=> [2, 2, 3]
x1.combination(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [2, 2, 3]:combination(2)>
```

We can see the objects that will be generated by this enumerator and passed to its block by converting it to an array.

```
x1.combination(2).to_a
  #=> [[2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

After computing

```
x1.combination(2) { |x| b << x }
  #=> [2, 2, 3]
```

(whose return value is of no interest) we obtain

```
 b #=> [[2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Then

```
x2 = b.reject { |x| x.sum != tg }
  #=> [[2, 2]]
c = x2[0]
  #=> [2, 2]
```

followed by

```
x3 = nums.index(c[0])
  #=> nums.index(2) => 0
x4 = nums.index(c[1])
  #=> nums.index(2) => 0
[x3, x4]
  #=> [0, 0]
```

We see the problem is that in computing both `x3` and `x4` we look for the first index `i` such that `nums[i]` equals `2`, which will be zero for both.

One way to remedy this is to use [Array#rindex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-rindex) when computing `x4`:

```
x4 = nums.rindex(c[1])
  #=> nums.rindex(2) => 1
```

---

Now let's see how we can improve upon this answer. The key is that while `nums` may contain duplicate values, the array of the indices of `nums`' values, `[0, 1, 2]`, does not. Since it is indices that we want it's easiest to begin with those indices, computing `num[i]` for each index `i` as needed:

```
a = (0..nums.size-1).to_a
  #=> [0, 1, 2] 
a.combination(2).find { |i,j| nums[i] + nums[j] == tg }
  #=> [0, 1]
```

Note `a` could be obtained in many ways. `nums.each_index.to_a` and `nums.size.times.to_a` are two. Also, the two operations might be chained:

```
nums.each_index.to_a.combination(2).find { |i,j| nums[i] + nums[j] == tg }
```

If preferred, to avoid the lookups `num[i]` one could instead write:

```
a = nums.each_with_index.to_a
  #=> [[2, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2]]
a.combination(2).find { |(ni,_i),(nj,_j)| ni + nj == tg }.map(&:last)
  #=> [0, 1]
```

Some Rubyists might choose to write this

```
nums.each_with_index
    .to_a
    .combination(2)
    .find { |(ni,_i),(nj,_j)| ni + nj == tg }
    .map(&:last)
```

or

```
nums.each_with_index.
     to_a.
     combination(2).
     find { |(ni,_i),(nj,_j)| ni + nj == tg }.
     map(&:last)
```

I've taken advantage of Ruby's [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) to express the block variables as I have. That reads better than

```
a.combination(2).find { |x1, x2| x1.first + x2.first == tg }.map(&:last)
```

I've named the two indices in the block as beginning with an underscore (`_i` and `_j`) to signal to the reader that they are not used in the block calculation. That's a common Ruby convention. It is perhaps more common (though arguably less descriptive) to use an underscore alone: `|(ni,_),(nj,_)|`.

`map(&:last)` is shortand for `map { |n,i| i }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def two_sum(nums, tg)
  b = []
  nums.sort.combination(2){|x| b << x}
  c = b.reject{|x| x.sum != tg}[0]
  h = (0..nums.size).map(&:to_i)
  h = h.zip(nums).to_h
  o = [h.key(c[0]), h.key(c[1])]
  o[0] == o[1] ? o[1]+1 : o
end
```

I added hash and 'if' statement

```
  h = (0..nums.size).map(&:to_i)
  h = h.zip(nums).to_h
  o = [h.key(c[0]), h.key(c[1])]
  o[0] == o[1] ? o[1]+1 : o
```

This part has changed! I added hash to get an index easier and then added if statement which adds +1 to the second index if both are the same.